# Read Text File and Keep Formatting

Tags: c#, .net, stream, formatting

I am attempting to read a file and set the text of a richTextBox equal to it, but the formatting is disappearing after I do so. The "ENTER"s within the text file itself are not visible in the richTextBox. Here is the code I am using:

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(directory + filePath))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            initialText += sr.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `sr.ReadLine()`, carriage return is removed from string (because it's the line terminator).
Try adding a CR after any line you read:

```
initialText += sr.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Anyway you'd better to use this easier and faster code:

```
initialText = File.ReadAllText(directory + filePath)
```

Comment: `ReadAllText` is definitely the way to go!